# error when loading json in sql server table with data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an error when loading a json with a nested matrix to a table in SQL Server with data factory, of the 32 columns at the end it loads 30 and two are left in cache, how can I solve this problem?

These are the columns that are being cached but are not loaded into the table.
[image]

The columns that are not loading are these.
[image]

When calculating the columns separately I get the following error "
Mistake:
at Sink 'sink1': No insertable columns match with the schema of sink table."

be able to solve this problem

Comment: What is the data type of those two columns in sql server?

Comment: Double is the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-sink)

> **A *cache sink* is when a data flow writes data into the Spark cache instead of a data store.** In mapping data flows, you can reference this data within the same flow many times using a *cache lookup*. This is useful when you want to reference data as part of an expression but don't want to explicitly join the columns to it.

The below error you are facing is because of discrepancy between the columns in your source data and the columns in your destination or sink table.

> Mistake: at Sink 'sink1': No insertable columns match with the schema of sink table."

To resolve this error in sink1 disable automapping and manually map the column.

[image]